# PHP MySQL join table

Tags: php, mysql, join

```
$sql = "SELECT logs.full_name, logout.status FROM logs, logout WHERE logs.employee_id = logout.employee_id";
```

```
tables --> logs
           logout
```

**I'm having error on this. I search join tables in google. And that's what I got. What is wrong with this code?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a "JOIN" anywhere in your query.

The correct syntax:

```
SELECT logs.full_name, logout.status FROM logs
    LEFT JOIN logout ON (logs.employee_id = logout.employee_id);
```

Comment: Your answer is correct but the results are only from logout table. I wanted to have a result that coming from the two tables.

Comment: Oh. I think thats not join tables. I found an answer using UNION. Thanks a lot in your answer. It helps me a lot. Thank you.